# PIC18F67K22 TX pin low after UART enable

Tags: uart, pic

I using PIC18F67K22 with MPLAB8.92 and ICD3.  I set port registers for UART RC7-input and RC6-output. I then set the UART 1 for comms. The Tx Pin should go high after setting UART but stays low. When I send a byte the Tx sends data and goes high after byte sent. I have played with the BAUDCON(5)(4) but no luck. Is it possible to force the Tx pin to go high without sending a byte ? All the data on the TX pin is correct after the first byte is sent.

```
    ;// Zeta

movlw   b'10010000' ;
MOVWF   TRISC   ;  


banksel TXSTA1 
movlw   b'10000000' ;// 
movwf   TXSTA1 

bsf BAUDCON1,3  ;// 16 byte

movlw   .207        ;// 64 mhz      
movwf   SPBRG1
movlw   .0
movwf   SPBRGH1     

movlw   b'10010000'
movwf   RCSTA1          ;//Enable Serial

bsf PIE1,5
```

Comment: Add `BSF PORC, 6`

Answer (score 1):

Before the UART is enabled use the TRISC and LATC registers to configure RC6 as an output and set the output state to one.

```
;
; Make the UART TX output a one.
;
    BANKSEL LATC
    BSF     LATC,6    ; Make RC6 a 1
    BANKSEL TRISC
    BCF     TRISC,6   ; Make RC6 an output
; 
; Now configure the UART and enable the TX
;
```

**EDIT 1**

This is a complete program that initializes the PIC and UART1:

```
    list n=0,c=250      ; Make list file pretty
    list r=dec          ; Use decimal as the default radix
;
; File:     main.asm
; Author:   dan1138
; Target:   PIC18F67K22
; Compiler: MPASMWIN v5.51
; IDE:      MPLAB v8.92
; 
;
;                                                PIC18F67K22
;            +----------+            +----------+            +-----------+            +----------+
;      <>  1 : RE1      :      <> 17 : RF1      :      <> 33 : RC2       :      <> 49 : RD7      :
;      <>  2 : RE0      :      -> 18 : ENVREG   :      <> 34 : RC3       :      <> 50 : RD6      :
;      <>  3 : RG0      :  5V0 -> 19 : AVDD     :      <> 35 : RC4       :      <> 51 : RD5      :
;      <>  4 : RG1      :  GND -> 20 : AVSS     :      <> 36 : RC5       :      <> 52 : RD4      :
;      <>  5 : RG2      :      <> 21 : RA3      :  PGD <> 37 : RB7/PGD   :      <> 53 : RD3      :
;      <>  6 : RG3      :      <> 22 : RA2      :  5V0 -> 38 : VDD       :      <> 54 : RD2      :
;  VPP ->  7 : RG5/MCLRn:      <> 23 : RA1      :      <> 39 : OSC1/RA7  :      <> 55 : RD1      :
;      <>  8 : RG4      :      <> 24 : RA0      :      <> 40 : OSC2/RA6  :  GND -> 56 : VSS      :
;  GND ->  9 : VSS      :  GND -> 25 : VSS      :  GND -> 41 : VSS       :  5V0 -> 57 : VDD      :
; 10uF -> 10 : VCAP     :  5V0 -> 26 : VDD      :  PGC <> 42 : RB6/PGC   :      <> 58 : RD0      :
;      <> 11 : RF7      :      <> 27 : RA5      :      <> 43 : RB5       :      <> 59 : RE7      :
;      <> 12 : RF6      :      <> 28 : RA4      :      <> 44 : RB4       :      <> 60 : RE6      :
;      <> 13 : RF5      :      <> 29 : RC1      :      <> 45 : RB3       :      <> 61 : RE5      :
;      <> 14 : RF4      :      <> 30 : RC0      :      <> 46 : RB2       :      <> 62 : RE4      :
;      <> 15 : RF3      :      <> 31 : RC6/TX   :      <> 47 : RB1       :      <> 63 : RE3      :
;      <> 16 : RF2      :      <> 32 : RC7/RX   :      <> 48 : RB0       :      <> 64 : RE2      :
;            +----------+            +----------+            +-----------+            +----------+
;                                                   TQFP-64
;
  INCLUDE "p18f67k22.inc"

; CONFIG1L
  CONFIG  RETEN = ON            ; VREG Sleep Enable bit (Enabled)
  CONFIG  INTOSCSEL = HIGH      ; LF-INTOSC Low-power Enable bit (LF-INTOSC in High-power mode during Sleep)
  CONFIG  SOSCSEL = HIGH        ; SOSC Power Selection and mode Configuration bits (High Power SOSC circuit selected)
  CONFIG  XINST = OFF           ; Extended Instruction Set (Disabled)

; CONFIG1H
  CONFIG  FOSC = INTIO2         ; Oscillator (Internal RC oscillator)
  CONFIG  PLLCFG = OFF          ; PLL x4 Enable bit (Disabled)
  CONFIG  FCMEN = OFF           ; Fail-Safe Clock Monitor (Disabled)
  CONFIG  IESO = OFF            ; Internal External Oscillator Switch Over Mode (Disabled)

; CONFIG2L
  CONFIG  PWRTEN = OFF          ; Power Up Timer (Disabled)
  CONFIG  BOREN = OFF           ; Brown Out Detect (Disabled in hardware, SBOREN disabled)
  CONFIG  BORV = 3              ; Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (1.8V)
  CONFIG  BORPWR = ZPBORMV      ; BORMV Power level (ZPBORMV instead of BORMV is selected)

; CONFIG2H
  CONFIG  WDTEN = OFF           ; Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled in hardware; SWDTEN bit disabled)
  CONFIG  WDTPS = 1048576       ; Watchdog Postscaler (1:1048576)

; CONFIG3L
  CONFIG  RTCOSC = SOSCREF      ; RTCC Clock Select (RTCC uses SOSC)

; CONFIG3H
  CONFIG  CCP2MX = PORTC        ; CCP2 Mux (RC1)
  CONFIG  MSSPMSK = MSK7        ; MSSP address masking (7 Bit address masking mode)
  CONFIG  MCLRE = ON            ; Master Clear Enable (MCLR Enabled, RG5 Disabled)

; CONFIG4L
  CONFIG  STVREN = ON           ; Stack Overflow Reset (Enabled)
  CONFIG  BBSIZ = BB2K          ; Boot Block Size (2K word Boot Block size)

; CONFIG5L
  CONFIG  CP0 = OFF             ; Code Protect 00800-03FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP1 = OFF             ; Code Protect 04000-07FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP2 = OFF             ; Code Protect 08000-0BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP3 = OFF             ; Code Protect 0C000-0FFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP4 = OFF             ; Code Protect 10000-13FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP5 = OFF             ; Code Protect 14000-17FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP6 = OFF             ; Code Protect 18000-1BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP7 = OFF             ; Code Protect 1C000-1FFFF (Disabled)

; CONFIG5H
  CONFIG  CPB = OFF             ; Code Protect Boot (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CPD = OFF             ; Data EE Read Protect (Disabled)

; CONFIG6L
  CONFIG  WRT0 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 00800-03FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT1 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 04000-07FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT2 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 08000-0BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT3 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 0C000-0FFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT4 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 10000-13FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT5 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 14000-17FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT6 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 18000-1BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT7 = OFF            ; Table Write Protect 1C000-1FFFF (Disabled)

; CONFIG6H
  CONFIG  WRTC = OFF            ; Config. Write Protect (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRTB = OFF            ; Table Write Protect Boot (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRTD = OFF            ; Data EE Write Protect (Disabled)

; CONFIG7L
  CONFIG  EBRT0 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 00800-03FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT1 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 04000-07FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT2 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 08000-0BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT3 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 0C000-0FFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT4 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 10000-13FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT5 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 14000-17FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT6 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 18000-1BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT7 = OFF           ; Table Read Protect 1C000-1FFFF (Disabled)

; CONFIG7H
  CONFIG  EBRTB = OFF           ; Table Read Protect Boot (Disabled)
;
; Define what we want the system clock frequency
; to be set to by the initialzation code.
;
#define FSYS (8000000)
#define FCYC (FSYS/4)
#define BAUD (9600)
#define BRG_VALUE (FSYS/BAUD)/4-1

;*******************************************************************************
; Reset Vector
;*******************************************************************************

RES_VECT  CODE    0x0000            ; processor reset vector
    GOTO    START                   ; go to beginning of program

;*******************************************************************************
; MAIN PROGRAM
;*******************************************************************************

MAIN_PROG CODE                      ; let linker place main program

START
    BSF     LATC,6                  ; Make TX output high
    BCF     TRISC,6                 ; Turn on output driver
    CLRF    RCSTA1                  ; Disable UART1
    CLRF    TXSTA1
    CLRF    BAUDCON1
    BSF     BAUDCON1,BRG16          ; Use 16-bit baud rate generator
    BSF     TXSTA1,BRGH             ; Select high speed baud rate generator
    BSF     TXSTA1,TXEN             ; Enable transmitter
    BSF     RCSTA1,CREN             ; Enable reciever
    MOVLW   LOW(BRG_VALUE)
    MOVWF   SPBRG1
    MOVLW   HIGH(BRG_VALUE)
    MOVWF   SPBRGH1
    BSF     RCSTA1,SPEN             ; Enable UART1
;
; With an 8MHz system clock this is about a 
; 100ms wait for UART1 hardware to be ready.
;
    MOVLW   0
    CLRF    PRODL
UART1_SpinWait:
    DECFSZ  PRODL,F
    BRA     UART1_SpinWait
    DECFSZ  WREG,F
    BRA     UART1_SpinWait

    MOVLW   '>'
    CALL    UART1_SendByte

    GOTO $                          ; loop forever
;
; Send a byte to UART1
;
UART1_SendByte:
    BTFSS   TXSTA1,TRMT             ; Skip when transmitter is empty
    BRA     UART1_SendByte
    MOVWF   TXREG
    RETURN

    END
```

See how this works in your hardware.

Comment: @Bobby, How is anyone to know? You do not show that part in your code fragment. If you are setting the TRISC and LATC register then your code is not working the way you want.

Comment: You are right my description was wrong, RC,6 is output set to 0 and RC,7 set to 1 input. I am monitoring the pins and shows high on RC,6 and once I enable UART the RC,6 drops to Gnd.

Comment: @Bobby, I added a complete application to my answer. See how it works in your hardware.